# What is the use of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I think random variables essentially convert outcomes into numbers and it is said that it is easier to deal with numbers. But what does it really mean? What exactly can we do with numbers that we couldn't do with outcomes?

Furthermore the [general definition](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/) of random variables is as a function whose codomain is not necessarily the reals with the Borel $\sigma$-field but is any measurable space. Exactly what is accomplished in this context.

Comment: For discrete sample spaces, it’s fine, but can be quite cumbersome. A sample space involving strings of $H$’s and $T$’s for $n$ tosses, is fine and all, but it’s much more useful to count the number of heads with $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ where $X_i$ are independent Bernoulli than it is to count the heads in $HHHHTHTHHHHH$. Further, for uncountable sample spaces it is *not necessary that every subset is even measurable* so you cannot always assign a probability. This is why we need $\sigma$-algebras and measurable functions, ie random variables, right?

Comment: I don't understand your second point. When we talk of random variables we a priory have a probability space (and hence a $\sigma$-algebra) so the probabilities are already assigned. Using random variables does not help in any assignment of probabilities anyway.

Comment: that’s true the chances are already assigned, but using random variables ensures every event in terms of them is automatically measurable and hence has a probability, whereas if you do not use random variables or use non-measurable functions or just use the outcomes themselves, there is no guarantee in general.

Comment: It is just not the chances that are already assigned but the entire probability space (theoretically) is well defined. That includes the underlying $\sigma$-algebra. So the events are also already well defined. (Are you saying that practically (and not theoretically) using random variables assist in telling which events are of interest? If so, can you please elaborate on this point with an example as an answer.)

Comment: the $\sigma$-algebra is not necessarily the power set of the space, so it is possible to find events that are not measurable, if you use anything but a measurable function to study events you might find yourself trying to find the probability of a subset of the sample-space that is non-measurable! I don’t know how to explain it in any other way. Sorry. I recommend David Williams incredible *Probability with Martingales* the entire introduction is devoted to the Branching process and how even for this simple stochastic process, measure-theory (and hence random variables) are required.

Comment: I know that the $\sigma$-algebra is not always a power set. My point was that, theoretically at least, we start with a probability space. So everything is already well known. The measurable sets (a.k.a. events) and their probabilities are known. After that we define a RV. So how can the RV tell us about what are the events?

Comment: suppose we take $([0,1], \mathscr{B}, Leb)$. We are interested in some arbitrary subset $A\subset [0,1]$. What is $Leb(A)$? We don’t even know if it’s a Borel set yet—that has to be decided before we can measure it. How do you propose to only stick to measurable subsets in the general abstract spaces on a systematic basis? The crucial aspect of RVs is that when we take the inverse images of Borel sets (or whatever the target measure space is) we always get back a proper event in the $\sigma$-algebra. But now I feel I’m repeating myself, hopefully someone wiser will come by...

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/250539/14875

Comment: yes I agree with that: random variables and stochastic processes are the central objects of study for probability theory and probability spaces are there to support them rigorously. Independence also makes probability theory quite distinguished from measure theory proper. Cheers!

Comment: Random variables are unavoidable when we apply probability to the real world: the amount of money you win in a game of chance, the number of people who respond "yes" to a survey question, the amount of time you must wait until a rare event occurs, the average of ten independent measurements of the mass of an object, are all examples of random variables. And one of the main reasons probability is so useful is because it allows us to draw conclusions about the values of such quantities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the main purpose of introducing random elements, i.e. functions from a sample space to some space having "nice" topological structure, is the ability to establish an integration theory with respect to the corresponding probability measures in order to be able to determine numerical characteristics of random measurements.

Comment: This makes sense. But it begs the question: Why don't we (usually) use the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra instead of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @Shahab There is an extensive discussion of this issue on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31603/why-do-probabilists-take-random-variables-to-be-borel-and-not-lebesgue-measura/31609).

Answer (score 3):

We can add, subtract, and otherwise process numbers, which also have structure (eg., relations such as *greater than*, *less than*) that general "outcomes" do not.  For instance, it makes sense to talk about the expected value of $x$, and the expected value of $x^2$.

Can't do that with an "outcome."

Comment: See the updated question

Answer (score 2):

I am not a professional probabilist, but I have thought about this question and here is my take.

One can think about the setup of modern probability theory as a way to model occurrences in real world that have "randomness" in them (whatever that means; say, for a running example, a throw of a dart to a dartboard). As such, one can conceptualize the "outcomes" as outcomes of some scientific experiment, or of occurrences in  the world (individual possible positions of a dart strike). However, the precise state of the world may be inaccessible, and one is only able to detect certain "events" (like a dart hitting certain zone on the dartboard). A random variable is a kind of summary of the outcome (the color of the board at the landing location, or the score earned by the throw, or the simple "hit or miss" binary random variable). In many situations the most useful information about the outcome is numerical - a numerical "measurement", i.e. a numeric random variable (the score is one type of example,  coordinates of the landing location in some coordinate system is another). This is why most widely used random variables are numeric -- it is simply the most useful way to summarize information in many applications (even outside probability theory, any "technical" field is full of numbers).

In addition, there is the philosophy one learns from [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/) and [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/275a-notes-0-foundations-of-probability-theory/) notes by Terry Taos, namely that in practice the random variables take on the main role, while "sample space essentially disappear from view altogether, after a few foundational issues are dispensed with" (it's not what generates the measurements that matters, it's the measurements themselves). In particular, one often has to **extend** the probability space one is working with, and "probability theory is only “allowed” to study concepts and perform operations which are preserved with respect to extension of the underlying sample space."  You should read at least initial sections of the above posts to get more on these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking about this question many times during my mathematics studies. If I understand your question correctly, you want to know why you should consider random variables and not directly its pushforward distribution.
My answer is that in probability theory you often want to study the dependence of several random variables, which is best illustrated by the following example.

Consider the example of throwing (independently) a regular dice twice and taking the sum:
$$
\Omega = \{1,\dots,6\}\times\{1,\dots,6\},
\quad
\mathbb P(\{(\omega_1,\omega_2)\}) = \frac{1}{36} \text{ for all } (\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\Omega,
\qquad
\tilde \Omega = \{2,\dots,12\},
\qquad
X\colon \Omega\to \tilde \Omega,\ (\omega_1,\omega_2)\mapsto \omega_1 + \omega_2.
$$
The random variable approach would be to consider the pushforward of $\mathbb P$ under $X$ and obtain $\mathbb P_X(\{2\}) = \frac{1}{36},\ \mathbb P_X(\{3\}) = \frac{2}{36},\ \mathbb P_X(\{8\}) = \frac{5}{36}$ etc.

Of course, you do not need to define the random variable to obtain this distribution, you could have just defined it directly, right?

But now assume you have a second random variable $Y(\omega_1,\omega_2) = \omega_1^2  -\omega_2$ (this is just some "complicated" example) and that you want to know $\mathbb P(Y\ge X)$. Computing it is cumbersome but doable using the random variable approach, but without random variables you would need to define a completely new probability space with a completely new distribution (now imagine you have 10 random variables...).

Try both approaches in this simple example and start appreciating random variables :-).